# Django - How to get user file path?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-forms

I have to accept excel file from user and perform some operation on it using pandas dataframe.

So to load the dataframe using pandas I need to pass the path of file:

```
fd =pd.read_excel('C:\users\chan\desktop\abc.xlsx')
```

In django I am trying to use *HTML input type file* to get the location of file, so that I can pass it in pandas but unable to get file location in python variable.

I tried below code but it's printing data on html page instead of storing it's path in variable:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Coordinates to Bounding Box</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="uploadbutton" type="file" value="Browse" name="file" accept="text/csv" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    {% block content %}
        <h3>File uploaded successfully</h3>
        {{file.name}}
        </br>content = {{contentOfFile}}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Django's views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def index(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file1 = request.FILES['file']
        contentOfFile = file1.read()
        if file1:
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'file': file1, 'contentOfFile': contentOfFile})
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Is there any way I can get the path of excel file or load the excel data in pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html you put:

```
<input type="file" name="excel_file" accept=".xlsx">
```

then in views.py:

```
excel_file = request.FILES.get('excel_file')
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting error as *Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>* and when I print excel_file it's just showing me the name of excel

Comment: @ShinChan check type of variable that holds the file it should be: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>. If you don't get this then probably is something wrong with you paths in url or something else.

Comment: Got it.. I was calling the main page after button click. Thanks :)